# If $X=\text{Spec}(A)$ where $A$ is a domain, then $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\bigcap_{p\in U}A_p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-schemes

I'm trying to prove the following:

> If $X=\text{Spec}(A)$ where $A$ is a domain, then $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\bigcap_{p\in U}A_p$ for any open $U\subset X$.

In the special case when $U$ is principal open set $X_f$, the claim is that $A_f=\bigcap_{p\in X_f}A_p$. The ring $B:=A_f$ is a domain and for every $p\in X_f$ we have isomorphisms $(A_f)_{pA_f}\simeq A_p$. By properties of primes in localizations, the claim amounts to:
$$B=\bigcap_{q\in\text{Spec}(B)}B_q$$

which is a well-known result for domains.

Now for the general case $U=\bigcup_i X_{f_i}$, I don't know what to do. I only know the formal definition 
$$\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\varprojlim_{X_f\subset U}A_f$$

and I don't know how to relate this to $\bigcap_{p\in U}A_p$.

How should I approach this?

Comment: A hint to get you started: why not try doing this for a polynomial ring over a field $k$ in a simple case.

Comment: @Alekos: in one variable all open sets are of the form $D(f)$. For a polynomial ring in several variables there is no simplification with respect to the general case. Care to show us why you think otherwise?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I suppose you're right! Personally, I find it psychologically easier to try to manufacture a proof for a polynomial case and then generalize it –– so that's why I suggested it.

Comment: @Alekos Fair enough: everyone is entitled to his psychological/intuitive vision.

Comment: Take a look at Example 2.37 of the book https://books.google.es/books?id=XEiLudn6sq4C&printsec=frontcover&hl=es&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false by Gortz and Wedhorn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quickest way to see this is as follows: The assignment $ \mathcal{R} $ which assigns to an open set $ U $ the ring $ \mathcal{R}(U) = \cap_{p \in U} A_p $ is clearly a sheaf and it agrees with the structure sheaf on the basic open sets $ \operatorname{Spec} A_f $. Since sheaves are uniquely determined by their values on a basis, $ \mathcal{R} = \mathcal{O}_X $.